# Как сохранить excel документ с русским названием phpexcel?

Tags: phpexcel

Привет всем! Использую PHP, PHPExcel.

Пишу скрипт, который берёт название таблицы из базы данных и сохраняет excel документ с его именем. Название таблицы на русском.

```
$objWriter->save('teachears/РусскиеБУКВЫ.xlsx');//вместо РусскиеБуквы - переменная хранящая название таблицы.
```

На выходе - файл имеет в названии непонятные иероглифы.

Возможно ли сохранить файл с русским названием? Или придётся писать костыль для перевода на английский?

---

Добавлено:

```
$connection = new mysqli("localhost", "admin", "1234", "teachers");
$connection->set_charset("utf8");
$query1 = "SHOW TABLES FROM `teachers`";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query1);

while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Демо');
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B1', 'Мир!');
...Код наполнения файла данными...
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
            $objWriter->save('teachears/'.$row1[0].'.xlsx');//где $row1[0] - название таблицы
}
```

Собственно, содержимое файла в порядке, проблема только в названии.

Comment: А вы попробовали? Мне кажется, поблем быть не должно. Главное следовать кодировке, в которой система хранит файлы

Comment: А, ну забыл написать, что в названии сохраненного файла появляется кракозябра)

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, пример (что пишете в коде и что получаете при просмотре списка файлов)

Comment: Какая кодировка у системы? Какая кодировка строк у php?

Comment: ммм.. в php.ini прописана стандартная - UTF-8. Из БД тоже приходит UTF8

Comment: @ZhiV И всё-таки, что в итоге получается? Например, чобы читать и писать кириллические файлы в Windows из php нужно переводить имена в CP1251, иначе большая часть просто не запишется, а некоторые даже потом будет проблемно стереть (есть у винды такой грех) или просто будут, как говорят, кракозяблики

Comment: @tutankhamun к примеру, при попытке сохранить файл Ыф.xlsx $objWriter->save('teachears/Ыф.xlsx');   ->   получается - Р«С„.xlsx

Comment: Воот. Тогда так: Переводите имена файлов в cp1251. Например так `$sysFilename = iconv('UTF-8', 'CP1251', $dbFilename);`

Comment: Не все UTF-8 символы могут быть переведены в 1251, причем по умолчанию встретив такой символ iconv отдаст пустую строку! Поэтому безопаснее будет использовать постфикс //IGNORE, а затем или перед тем еще preg_replace-ом непотребные знаки почистить.

Comment: @tutankhamun спасибо, помогло! Напиши это как ответ, я лайкну))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Резюмирую комментарии:

При создании файлов в php следует учитывать кодировку имени файла, поддерживаемую файловой системой и функциями операционной системы.

Например, для Windows (по признакам видно что именно в этой среде запускается скрипт топикстартером) php-скрипт должен использовать кодировку **cp1251**, поскольку файлы в php создаются API функцией `CreateFileA` (по крайней мере именно она есть в списке импорта php5ts.dll).

Задачу, указанную в вопросе, решает строка `$sysFilename = iconv('UTF-8', 'CP1251//IGNORE', $dbFilename);` (как верно подсказал *artoodetoo*).

Дополнительно может понадобиться фильтрация имен файлов на предмет содержания в них запрещенных символов (для Windows это `<>:"/\|?*` и "нулевой" символ), а также обрезка до разрешенной длины (для Windows - 255 символов) [см. Naming Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#naming_conventions)

PS. На всякий случай проверил. В Windows нужно проверять длину пути. Из php файл не создается если длина пути больше 255 (что странно, в документации написано про 260 символов)

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = 'Остатки на '. $date;
$Filename = iconv('UTF-8', 'CP1251//IGNORE', $file);
```